# Using arguments with a PHP script in HTML

Tags: php

How can I pass an argument to a php script in this:

```
<?php require '../scripts/listPictures.php'; ?>
```

Adding my argument at the end causes the whole script to break and using vardump on argv just returns null.

Comment: Why not make the contents of listPictures a function call, then call that method in your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't send arguments because include/require runs the script as if you just wrote it in that place.

So just check what parameters that script needs (something in the session? on the request? a variable perhaps?) and set it before the require.

A better approach would to turn whatever is inside that listPictures.php into a function, so you could actually send parameters

Alban reply is like too much for too little. Creating an class, instancing it, calling it, only for some simple task =p I rather either make a function inside that, since it's easier, cleaner, faster (both to do and for php to run) and uses less memory

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to do this is to use a class and then add all parameters to it like that :

```
class View
{
    private $partial;
    private $data;

    function __construct($partial, $data = array())
    {
        $this->partial = $partial;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    function __get($name)
    {
        return (isset($this->data[$name]))
            ? $this->data[$name]
            : null;
    }

    function render()
    {
        ob_start();
        include($this->partial);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Then you can call your view like that :

```
$view = new View("../scripts/listPictures.php", array("name" => "Ghilliedrone"));
```

Here is the content of listPictures.php :

```
<h1>Hello ! My name is <?php echo $this->name; ?> !</h1>
```

You can also directly display your view using echo :

```
<?php echo new View("../scripts/listPictures.php", array("name" => "Ghilliedrone")); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, if you're not declaring things like functions and classes in the listPictures.php file:

```
function listPictures($arg1, $arg2) {
    return require '../scripts/listPictures.php';
}
```